# Чем обусловлены названия букв с "а" на конце?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фонетика, алфавит, историческая-фонетика, буквы

Почему такие буквы, как "х" и "к", называются "ха" и "ка", а не "хэ" и "кэ" либо "эх" и "эк"?

Answer (score 0):

Преемственность поколений. В оригинале (у финикийцев) и у арабов до сих пор почти все буквы такие, будь-то "ха", "та", "ба" и вот это вот всё. хотя радоваться не стоит, там же есть "аин", "син", "шин" и прочие "каф". Всё нормально.